# How to find the value(s) that is most distant from the average using a loop?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to write a java program which read data from a text file and calculate some different averages according to the given question.

The file I'm given contains 13 different decimal numbers (indicated in the first line of the file)

I'm trying to find:

- The average of all values. (Call this average A1.)
- The average of all values, excluding the one furthest from A1. (Call this average A2.)
- The average of all values, excluding the two furthest from A2. (Call this average A3.)
- The average of all values, excluding the three furthest from A3.
- . . .
- The average of all values, excluding the N-1 furthest from A(N-1). (This is the average of just one element; in other words, the value of that element itself.)

Here is my code. I managed to get A1, A2, A3,and A4, but I don't know what to do next. (I feel that I should use a loop but I don't know how)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FurtherTweeking
{ public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException {

//Read the given file
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\src\\ArrayList.txt"));
//The first line of the file gives the number of values that follow
int Num = scan.nextInt();

//Reads the data into an array
Double[] InputData = new Double[Num];
double ArraySum = 0;
int i = 0;
do {
    InputData[i] = scan.nextDouble();
    i = i+1;
}
while(scan.hasNextLine());
scan.close();






//Calculate the sum of all input data
for (int j = 0; j < Num; j++ ) {
    if (InputData[j] != null) {
        ArraySum = ArraySum + InputData[j];
    }
}
//Calculate the average of the original input data
double A1 = ArraySum/(Num);
System.out.println("A1: " + A1);





//Scan through the array to find the value that is farthest (in either direction) from the average
double Farthest = InputData[0];
for (int j = 0; j < Num; j++ ) {
    if (InputData[j] != null) {
        if ( Math.abs ( A1 - InputData[j] ) > Math.abs ( A1 - Farthest ) )
            Farthest = InputData[j];
    }
}
for (int u = 0; u < Num; u++){
    if (InputData[u] == Farthest ){
        InputData[u] = null;
    }
}
System.out.println("Most distant value: " + Farthest);
//compute an average that does not include the most distant value. Print the new average.
double A2 = ( ArraySum - Farthest )/( Num - 1.0 );
System.out.println("A2: " + A2 );






double Farthest2 = InputData[0];
double Farthest3 = InputData[0];
for (int j = 0; j < Num; j++ ) {
    if (InputData[j] != null) {
        if ( Math.abs ( A2 - InputData[j] ) > Math.abs ( A2 - Farthest2 ) ) {
            Farthest3 = Farthest2;
            Farthest2 = InputData[j];
        }
        else if ( Math.abs ( A2 - InputData[j] ) > Math.abs ( A2 - Farthest3 ) ) {
            Farthest3 = InputData[j];
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Most distant value: " + Farthest2 + ", " + Farthest3);
//compute an average that does not include the most distant value. Print the new average.
double A3 = ( ArraySum - Farthest - Farthest2 - Farthest3 )/( Num - 3.0 );
System.out.println("A3: " + A3 );





double Farthest4 = InputData[0];
double Farthest5 = InputData[0];
double Farthest6 = InputData[0];
for (int j = 0; j < Num; j++ ) {
    if (InputData[j] != null) {
        if ( Math.abs ( A3 - InputData[j] ) > Math.abs ( A3 - Farthest4 ) ) {
            Farthest6 = Farthest5;
            Farthest5 = Farthest4;
            Farthest4 = InputData[j];
        }
        else if ( Math.abs ( A3 - InputData[j] ) > Math.abs ( A3 - Farthest5 ) ) {
            Farthest6 = Farthest5;
            Farthest5 = InputData[j];
        }
        else if ( Math.abs ( A3 - InputData[j] ) > Math.abs ( A3 - Farthest6 ) ) {
            Farthest6 = InputData[j];
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Most distant value: " + Farthest4 + ", " + Farthest5+ ", " + Farthest6);
//compute an average that does not include the most distant value. Print the new average.
double A4 = ( ArraySum - Farthest - Farthest2 - Farthest3 -Farthest4 - Farthest5 - Farthest6 )/( Num - 6.0 );
System.out.println("A4: " + A4 );
}
}
```

Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: Note that this problem is not well defined.  At any stage, if smallest and largest values are  equidistant from the average then which do you remove?  Your choice will affect all subsequent averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create two util functions:

```
/** Returns the average of a collection of double */
private static Double average(Collection<Double> coll) {
  return coll.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::doubleValue));
}

/** Returns the first, most distant element of a collection from a defined value. */
private static Double furthest(Collection<Double> coll, Double value) {
  return coll.stream()
    .max((d1, d2) -> Double.compare(Math.abs(d1-value), Math.abs(d2-value)))
    .orElse(null);
}
```

And use them like this:

```
Double[] array = new Double[]{1d,2d,3d,4d,5d,6d,7d,8d,9d};
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

  double average = average(list);
  System.out.printf("Average A%d: %.1f, List: %s\n", (i+1), average, input);

  double furthest = furthest(list, average);
  list.remove(furthest);
}
```

Output:

```
Average A1: 5.0, List: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
Average A2: 5.5, List: [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
Average A3: 6.0, List: [3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
Average A4: 6.5, List: [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
Average A5: 7.0, List: [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
Average A6: 7.5, List: [6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
Average A7: 8.0, List: [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
Average A8: 8.5, List: [8.0, 9.0]
Average A9: 9.0, List: [9.0]
```

Comment: Absolute differences in Double.compare() ?

Comment: You're right, thanks. Now the first furthest one is returned by `furthest()`

Comment: And may be it would be better to choose some other numbers for getting no so strange output?

Comment: Why strange? It looks like a clear and intuitive example to me... anyway it is just an example, I tested with @Shadov numbers and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrote something a lot more complicated that your task needs to be (if I understood your task correctly). Imagine if you didn't have 13 numbers, but even like a thousand, what then? I wrote you a little something, that may not exactly be what you need (but I'm not sure, it may be), but it's gonna show you the idea how something like this can be done, I left prints in code so you could see what actually happens, I suggest you run this code.

```java
public static void main(String arg[]) {
  List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3.2, 4.8, 5.2, 1.2, 9.8, 0.5, 6.6, 2.2, 7.1));

  while(list.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Next iteration, list: " + list);
    DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = list.stream().collect(DoubleSummaryStatistics::new,
        DoubleSummaryStatistics::accept, DoubleSummaryStatistics::combine);
    double average = stats.getAverage();
    double min = stats.getMin();
    double max = stats.getMax();
    double furthest = Math.abs(average - max) > Math.abs(average - min) ? max : min;
    System.out.println("Average: " + average);
    System.out.println("Minimum: " + min);
    System.out.println("Maximum: " + max);
    System.out.println("Furthest away: " + furthest);
    list.remove(furthest);
  }
}
```

What we do here is we count the [DoubleSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) on the list (it counts the average, max, min etc. for us, have a look at the link) and then we just take the values we need. The value that is furthest away may be either maximum or minimum so we need to find this value ourselves. Then we remove that value from the list and do it all over again, until there are no elements in the list.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't very understand that what's the purpose for changing the array into a list? (Sorry if this is a stupid question)

Comment: I just prefer to work with lists in this example, `ArrayList` uses arrays internally as the name implies, but it's packed with a lot of useful methods and it 'grows bigger' with item insertions and a lot of other things, google the `java Lists vs Arrays` or something like that, you will find a lot :) In this example I used list, because we need to remove futhest item from it, wouldn't be so easy with array, other changes would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Using collections will be slow for large lists, maybe o(n*2).
Instead, an efficient implementation for n values would be...

```
1. Put all values in a double[] array
2. Sort array with Arrays.sort(double[n]).  Time is o(n*log(n))
3. Calculate sum of array
4. Setup markers a=0 and b=n-1
5. Now each smaller average requires clipping at start or end of list, which corresponds to incrementing a or decrementing b
```

With the above algorithm all the averages can be found in o(n*log(n)) + o(n) = o(n*log(n)).   Much faster, and also uses much less memory.

Here is the code for a fast solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] arD = {3.2, 4.8, 5.2, 1.2, 9.8, 0.5, 6.6, 2.2, 7.1};
        Arrays.sort(arD);

        double sum = 0;
        for (double d : arD)
            sum += d;

        int n = arD.length;
        int a = 0, b = n - 1;
        while (a <= b) {
            int m = b - a + 1;
            double avg = sum / m;
            System.out.println("Average of  range=[" + a + "," + b + "] is " + avg);
            if (Math.abs(arD[a] - avg) > Math.abs(arD[b] - avg))
                sum -= arD[a++];
            else
                sum -= arD[b--];
        }

    }
}
```